# Looping through Numpy array and slicing

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am working on a certain task which uses numpy.
I have the following array:

```
A = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
```

And I have another variable called B which is of shape (10, 10).
What I want to do is basically loop through the array A and do the following:

```
B[1,2]
B[3,4]
B[5,6]
B[7,8]
```

All of these should return a single number and not a numpy array.

I have tried converting the array A to list and then loop through the list to take the 2 consecutive elements. But I was wondering whether there is a better method to achieve this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop

Setting up an example

```
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
B = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
B
```

Out:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
 [70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]]
```

You can index with `A`

```
B[A[:,0], A[:,1]]
```

Out:

```
array([12, 34, 56, 78])
```

Comment: Yep, thank you! This is what I was looking for. Numpy indexing gets me everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    print(B[A[i][0], A[i][1]])
```

Comment: Yes this works, I wanted to actually check the result without using a for loop (the next answer). Thank you for your help.